# How to create a Python venv and git clone to the same directory?

Tags: python-3.x, git-clone, python-venv

I want to clone a git repo, and create a Python virtual environment in the same directory ( Python 3.8.2 ),

so that if I activate the virtual environment, I can run a .py anywhere in the repo dir at the top level or any sub-dir, it will run within the virtual environment.

---

The preferred way of setting up a virtual environment using Python 3 is:

```
python -m venv <path>
```

This will create the `<path>` directory, if it does not exist, and populate it with the following:

```
Include/
Lib/
Scripts/
pyvenv.cfg
```

If the `<path>` specified exists, and is not empty, then it will fail.

---

If then you try then to clone a git repo to the same directory, and it is not empty, the git clone will fail.

Given that when running each command, the directory must be empty, how to work this?

**Say I want to git clone to:**

```
C:\dev\repos\my_project
```

Where I have created a virtual env and the three directories and one file above exist, the git clone will fail.

---

Essentially I need to clone a git repo (Python code), create a virtual env **in that same top level directory**, activate and run a python script in that directory (or in any sub-dir under the repo dir, and have it run in the venv).

Is this the way things work?

---

I am activating the directory using Windows Powershell, by first cd'ing to the directory

```
C:>cd c:\dev\repos\my_project
```

then activating the venv by typing:

```
C:\dev\repos\my_project>Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

Comment: Why does the virtual environment need to be in the same top-level directory as the local repository? In my experience the venv will take effect wherever the call to `activate` is made from, even if the venv was created in a subdirectory.

Comment: that works, I posted what I figured out below, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

Ultimately I created a sub dir in the top level repo directory for each env like:

`/.venv_py377/` and 
`/.venv_py382/`

and this works by calling `<env>/Activate.ps1` from the repo directory referencing which version of Python I need activated.